# Jquery - DateTimePicker set max datetime

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

I have 2 datetimepicker. 1 is `From`, another is `To`.  how to I limit my `To` datetimepicker to be 30 minutes after `From`?
I know how to limit the maximum date, but I dont know how to limit the maximum date and time.

for example :

If `From` is `2016/05/11 00:00` then max of `To` would be `2016/05/11 00:30`
But, if `From is`2016/05/11 23:55`then max of`To`would be`2016/05/12 00:25`

my current code :

```
$("#From").datetimepicker({
    onClose: function (selectedDate, instance) {
       if (selectedDate != '') {
           $("#To").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
           var date = $.datepicker.parseDateTime("dd/mm/yy", "hh:mm", selectedDate);
           date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 30);
           $("#To").datetimepicker("option", "maxTime", selectedDate);
        }
    }
});
$("#To").datetimepicker();
```

this code is not working, and Im at a loss. Should I set the `maxDate` and `maxTime` separately?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `e.date` which is a [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) instance, then you can easily do `e.date.add(30, 'minutes')`, like this:

```
var fromDP = $("#From").datetimepicker();
var toDP = $("#To").datetimepicker();

fromDP.on("dp.change", function(e){
    var newDate = e.date.add(30, 'minutes');
    toDP.data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(newDate);
});
```

working example [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/f6gmdgLn/1/)

..and if you want to set it as default date aswell you can do

```
toDP.data("DateTimePicker").date(newDate).maxDate(newDate);
```

Comment: is it only working if I use `Datetimepicker for Bootstrap 3` ? because with bootstrap, if its 10:59. and I add 1 more min, it would be 11:00 automatically. but thats not the case by default `Datetimepicker`

Comment: @Mark, what do you mean by _default Datetimepicker_? Which plugin are you using?