# Set max and min datetime in jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using jquery datetimepicker.In which i want to set mindate and time which is the value selected in second datetimepicker.

What i tried is :

```
$('#date_start').datetimepicker({
        autoSize: true,
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
             $('#date_end').datetimepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
        }
    });
```

I refered this [Jquery - DateTimePicker set max datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156602/jquery-datetimepicker-set-max-datetime) link.But its not a clear solution for my issue.

```
$('#date_end').datetimepicker({
        autoSize: true,
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $('#date_start').datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
        }
    });
```

Actually this same code is working for only  datepicker.But if i want it to work in datetimepicker.

What is the solution?

Comment: Could you provide link to the plugin you are using.??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: I am afraid that they have option for that along with `timepicker` because I saw a demo in their page where they have range picker [the last demo in the above link given by you], wherein they have disabled `timepicker`, still you can see at option `onShow` provided in the same demo. Alongside, I assume you have purchased the plugin, if so, why not ask for their assistance in this?

Comment: Always use libraries which are updated timely and have good support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **[plugin](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)** you have provided,
there is no option like `onSelect`.

Use `onSelectDate` and `onSelectTime` or **[`onShow`](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#onShow)**,

```
$('#date_start').datetimepicker({
    minDate:'-1970/01/02',
    minTime:'11:00'
});
```

or at runtime,

```
var setMin = function( currentDateTime ){
  this.setOptions({
      minDate:'-1970/01/02'
  });
  this.setOptions({
      minTime:'11:00'
  });
};

$('#date_start').datetimepicker({
    onShow:setMin
});
```

References:

1. [minDate](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#minDate)
2. [maxDate](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#maxDate)
3. [minTime](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#minTime)
4. [maxTime](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#maxTime)

Comment: On select of one dateTime picker i want to set min date and time of another dateTimepicker. 'onChangeDateTime' is working for me.But setting dateTime dynamically not working

Comment: Use the code above to work out your problem. The API is available. Ue `setOptions` instead of your current code.

Comment: I made some changes and it helped me to get the solution. thank u :)

Comment: @Webie i have same problem can you please tell how you did this. Thanks

Comment: @ShaunakD And what if you want to enable `minTime` but only for the current day. As in its currently 17:00, and I don't want to allow anyone picking 16:00. But tomorrow 16:00 gotta be available again.