# set datetimepicker's minimum date to another datetimepicker's selected date

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have two textboxes: txtETCdatefrom and txtETCdateto having classes datetimepicker1 and datetimepicker2 respectively:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtETCdatefrom" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datetimepicker1 col-md-6"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtETCdateto" runat="server" CssClass="col-md-6 datetimepicker2 form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am using datetimepicker with date only format on both classes(It is working fine if i set minDate to any specific date or moment()). 
I want to set minimum date of datetimepicker2 to selected value of datetimepicker1 or value of txtETCdatefrom.
My datetimepicker code is:

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    minDate: moment(),
                });            
$('.datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    //minDate: moment(),                   
                });
```

I searched about this and found answer for datepicker(using onSelect() function):

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
             format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
             minDate: moment(),
             onSelect: function (date) {
             var date1 = $('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('getDate');
             var date = new Date(Date.parse(date1));
             date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
             var newDate = date.toDateString();
             newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));
             $('.datetimepicker2').datetimepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);
             }
       });
$('.datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    //minDate: moment(),
                });
```

but it is not working for datetimepicker. 
I also tried beforeShow() function like:

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    minDate: moment(),
                });
$('.datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    //minDate: moment(),
                    beforeShow: function () {
                        $(".datetimepicker2").datetimepicker("option", {
                        minDate: $(".datetimepicker1").datetimepicker('getDate')
                        });
                    }
                });
```

but all vain. Also tried onSelectDate() and onShow() functions as suggested in 
[Set max and min datetime in jquery datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045507/set-max-and-min-datetime-in-jquery-datetimepicker)
don't know what m doing wrong.
After including these functions in code the datetimepicker doesn't show up.
All help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're using [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) because I think that is initialized using $().datepicker() instead of $().datetimepicker(). Can you check that?

Comment: And here's how they recommend using [min and max](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max). Try using a javascript date object instead of a moment() or a date string. Momentjs provides a function to convert the moment() to a javascript date object.

Comment: @Yatin i am using bootstrap datetimepicker not datepicker and i am not finding solution for datetimepicker. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I follow the docs in [datepicker official website](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

```js
$(function () {
       
       $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    minDate: moment(),
                });            
      
      
      $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                });
      
      $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            var oldDate = new Date(e.date);
            var newDate = new Date();
            newDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() + 1);

            $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(newDate);          
        });
      
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow!! it worked. Thank you so much.Wondering how i didnt found that. anyway you really saved my day..!!

Comment: Now i got another problem its working for my first two textboxes only but not for others. How can i fix it

Comment: @Preet What does 'others' means?

Comment: it means for other textboxes on my page. i used different id's instead of class and it worked thanks @Nico

Comment: @Preet I found maybe you need add 1 day in datetimepicker2, so i update the answer for you. Have a nice day!

Comment: yeah i need that in some cases. u too